# Why would the query show data from the wrong month?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query:

```
;with date_cte as(
SELECT r.starburst_dept_name,r.monthly_past_date as PrevDate,x.monthly_past_date as CurrDate,r.starburst_dept_average - x.starburst_dept_average as Average
FROM
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY starburst_dept_name ORDER BY monthly_past_date) AS rowid
    FROM intranet.dbo.cse_reports_month
) r
JOIN
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY starburst_dept_name ORDER BY monthly_past_date) AS rowid
    FROM intranet.dbo.cse_reports_month
    Where month(monthly_past_date) > month(DATEADD(m,-2,monthly_past_date))
) x
    ON r.starburst_dept_name = x.starburst_dept_name AND r.rowid = x.rowid+1
    Where r.starburst_dept_name is NOT NULL
)
Select *
From date_cte
Order by Average DESC
```

So doing some testing, I have alter some columns data, to see why it gives me certain information. I don't know why when I run the query it gives my a date column that should not be there from "january" (row 4) like the picture below:
[image]

The database has more data that has the same exact date '2014-01-25 00:00:00.000', so I'm not sure why it would only get that row and compare the average?

I did before I run the query alter the column in that row and change the date? But I'm not sure if that would have something to do with it.

UPDATE:
I have added the sqlfinddle,
What I would like to get it subtract the average 
from last_month - last 2 month ago. 
It Was actually working until I made a change and alter the data.
I made the changes to test a certain situation, which obviously lead 
to learning that there are flaws to the query.

Comment: A SQL Fiddle would be nice to help with this issue by the way

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d74b6/1

Answer (score 0):

Based on your SQL Fiddle, this eliminates joins from prior than month-2 from showing up.

```
SELECT
    thismonth.starburst_dept_name
   ,lastmonth.monthtly_past_date [PrevDate]
   ,thismonth.monthtly_past_date [CurrDate]
   ,thismonth.starburst_dept_average - lastmonth.starburst_dept_average as Average
FROM dbo.cse_reports thismonth
inner join dbo.cse_reports lastmonth on
    thismonth.starburst_dept_name = lastmonth.starburst_dept_name
    AND month(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,thismonth.monthtly_past_date))=month(lastmonth.monthtly_past_date)
WHERE MONTH(thismonth.monthtly_past_date)=month(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
Order by thismonth.starburst_dept_average - lastmonth.starburst_dept_average DESC
```